# how to start webkit animation after page load?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an animation with my header wrapper and I want the animation to start after the page completely loads.

However it seems like it starts before the page loads. I looked up a function on css tricks and that is what i am using here.

It seems the animation starts a little early. Any help with this?

From the post on css tricks i added a class "preload" to the body and then removed the class in my JavScript to start the animation but does not seem to work.

```
<!---------------------------HTML ------------------------>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en-us">

    <head>

      <title>Carlos Elizondo</title>    
      <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "main.css">

      <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">

      <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "animate.css">

      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet">



    </head>

    <body class = "preload">

<!------------------------------------------------------------HEADER------------------------------------------------------------------>        
      <header>
          <div class="header-bg"></div>

          <div class="header-dark">

            <div class="wrapper anim fadeInDown">

                <div class = "heading">Hi. My Name is</div>

                <div class = "box-name">Carlos Elizondo</div>

                <div class = "heading">I'm a future web developer and current student </div>

              <ul>

                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="ion-social-facebook"></a>
                </li>

                <li>
                  <a href="#" class="ion-social-twitter"></a>
                </li>

                <li>
                  <a href="#" class="ion-social-linkedin"></a>
                </li>

              </ul>

            </div>

          </div>

          <nav class = "clearfix">

              <a href = "#contact-title" class = "nav-links last">Contact</a>

              <a href = "#portfolio" class = "nav-links">Portfolio</a>

              <a href = "#skills" class = "nav-links">Skills</a>

              <a href = "#about-me" class = "nav-links ">About Me</a>

          </nav>

        </header>
    </body>
</html>


<!--------------------------------------CSS------------------------------>

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


body{
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    padding: 0;
}

.clearfix::after{
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.preload * {
  -webkit-transition: none !important;
  -moz-transition: none !important;
  -ms-transition: none !important;
  -o-transition: none !important;
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------HEADER-----------------------------------------------------------------------*/

header{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0;


}

.header-bg{

    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(macbook2.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;

}

.header-dark{

    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

}

.wrapper{

    width: 850px;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: -50px;


}


h2{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;

}

h4{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}

ul{   

    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 20px;

}

ul li{

    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 13px;


}


.ion-social-facebook{
   color: white;
   font-size: 28px;

}

.ion-social-facebook:visited{
    color: white;
}

.ion-social-facebook:visited{
    color: white;
}

.ion-social-twitter{

    color: white;
    font-size: 28px;
}

.ion-social-linkedin{
    color: white;
    font-size: 28px;
}


nav{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 100;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);

}

.nav-links{
    float: right;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 20px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-links.last{
    margin-right: 30px;
}

nav > a{
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;

}

nav > a:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    bottom: -3px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    transform: scaleX(0);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;   

}

nav a:hover:before{
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
}

.logo:link{

    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    float: left;

}

.heading{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;

}

.box-name{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    border: 6px solid white;
    padding: 9px;
    font-size: 75px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.anim{
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;

}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInDown{
    0%{
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-60px);
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    }
}

@keyframes fadeInDown{
    0%{
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-60px);
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    }
}

.fadeInDown{
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInDown;
    animation-name: fadeInDown;
}

<!-----------------------------------------JS------------------------------>

$(window).load(function() {
  $("body").removeClass("preload");
});
```

Comment: [Check this Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40877362/5236174)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove `.fadeInDown` class from wrapper div
2. Make wrapper div `display:none` by default.
3. Add `display:block !important;` CSS to `.fadeInDown` class
4. On page ready add `.fadeInDown` class to wrapper div.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".wrapper").addClass("fadeInDown");
});
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


body{
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    padding: 0;
}

.clearfix::after{
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.preload * {
  -webkit-transition: none !important;
  -moz-transition: none !important;
  -ms-transition: none !important;
  -o-transition: none !important;
}

header{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0;


}

.header-bg{

    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(macbook2.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;

}

.header-dark{

    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

}

.wrapper{

    width: 850px;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: -50px;


}


h2{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;

}

h4{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}

ul{   

    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 20px;

}

ul li{

    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 13px;


}


.ion-social-facebook{
   color: white;
   font-size: 28px;

}

.ion-social-facebook:visited{
    color: white;
}

.ion-social-facebook:visited{
    color: white;
}

.ion-social-twitter{

    color: white;
    font-size: 28px;
}

.ion-social-linkedin{
    color: white;
    font-size: 28px;
}


nav{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 100;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);

}

.nav-links{
    float: right;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 20px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-links.last{
    margin-right: 30px;
}

nav > a{
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;

}

nav > a:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    bottom: -3px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    transform: scaleX(0);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;   

}

nav a:hover:before{
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    transform: scaleX(1);
}

.logo:link{

    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    float: left;

}

.heading{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;

}

.box-name{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    border: 6px solid white;
    padding: 9px;
    font-size: 75px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.anim{
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    -animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;

}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeInDown{
    0%{
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-60px);
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    }
}

@keyframes fadeInDown{
    0%{
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-60px);
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
    }
}

.fadeInDown{
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInDown;
    animation-name: fadeInDown;
    display:block !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en-us">

    <head>

      <title>Carlos Elizondo</title>    
      <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "main.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

      <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">

      <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "animate.css">

      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet">



    </head>

    <body class="preload">

<!------------------------------------------------------------HEADER------------------------------------------------------------------>        
      <header>
          <div class="header-bg"></div>

          <div class="header-dark">

            <div class="wrapper anim" style='display:none'>

                <div class = "heading">Hi. My Name is</div>

                <div class = "box-name">Carlos Elizondo</div>

                <div class = "heading">I'm a future web developer and current student </div>

              <ul>

                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="ion-social-facebook"></a>
                </li>

                <li>
                  <a href="#" class="ion-social-twitter"></a>
                </li>

                <li>
                  <a href="#" class="ion-social-linkedin"></a>
                </li>

              </ul>

            </div>

          </div>

          <nav class = "clearfix">

              <a href = "#contact-title" class = "nav-links last">Contact</a>

              <a href = "#portfolio" class = "nav-links">Portfolio</a>

              <a href = "#skills" class = "nav-links">Skills</a>

              <a href = "#about-me" class = "nav-links ">About Me</a>

          </nav>

        </header>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: animation is not starting because the display is none i believe?

Comment: check #3 in ans. Add display:block !important; CSS to .fadeInDown also checkout .fadeInDown css in code snippet. That will make it visible again.

Comment: this is weird but it is not showing the animation but when i run the code on codepen it works fine any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Open console and see it adds fadeInDown class correctly. And do compare css, JavaScript, HTML with your code. If there is any jQuery error you can see that in console.

Answer (score 1):

This `preload` class prevents transitions, but not keyframe animations. It's also a bit hacky.

Instead of *removing* a class on page load, it might make more sense to add the `fadeInDown` class in your `$(window).load` function, which will cause the CSS animation to run immediately after the class is added. Just remember to remove that class from the HTML, as it will now be added in JS.

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $(".wrapper").addClass("fadeInDown");
});
```

Comment: remove the fadeInClass or preload class?

Comment: You can remove all references to `preload`, but I mean specifically to remove `fadeInDown` from your HTML because it'll now be added via the above snippet of JS. So, change the HTML to be `<div class="wrapper anim">`